# wp_mail not sending when adding headers

Tags: wordpress

Emails are being sent successfully but I want to send email to include a footer html template, so i've added the following lines:

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";    
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
```

Now emails aren't being sent.  How do i solve this?

```
$emails = array("test@gmail.com");
        $emails = array_unique($emails);
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $message.="<div class='footer'>
        <ul style='padding: 0;margin: 0;'>
            <li><img style='width:300px' src='https://www.test.co.uk/wp-content/themes/test/images/structural/head-logo.jpg' /></li>
            <li style='list-style-type: none;margin-bottom:6px;'><span style='color: #73a724;font-weight: bold;'>Tel:</span> +44 203 051 1214</li>
            <li style='list-style-type: none;margin-bottom:6px;'><span style='color: #73a724;font-weight: bold;'>Fax:</span> +44 207 657 3322</li>
            <li style='list-style-type: none;margin-bottom:6px;'><span style='color: #73a724;font-weight: bold;'>E-mail:</span> info@test.co.uk </li>
            <li style='list-style-type: none;margin-bottom:6px;'><span style='color: #73a724;font-weight: bold;'>Web:</span> www.test.co.uk</li>
        </ul>
    </div>";
                $headers = 'From: test <info@test.co.uk>' . "\r\n"; 
                $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";    
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";

                $success = wp_mail( $emails, $subject, $message, $headers );  //send emails
```

Comment: WordPress is just passing the stuff off to PHP's default function. Try putting the from part of the headers after the mime and content types.

Comment: Tried but still didn't work.. only works when i remove the mime/content-type

Comment: Take a look at your mail logs on your server to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I has seen this code. There is no thing wrong with that header excerpt you don't need this line:

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

wp_mail will automatic added it for you.

Secondly, Try this code:

```
    $emails = "yourmail@gmail.com";
    //$emails .= ', ' . 'test2@gmail.com';

    $subject = !empty($_POST['subject']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['subject']) : 'test subject';
    $message = !empty($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';

    $message.="<div class='footer'>
            <ul style='padding: 0;margin: 0;'>
                <li><img style='width:300px' src='https://www.test.co.uk/wp-content/themes/test/images/structural/head-logo.jpg' /></li>
                <li style='list-style-type: none;margin-bottom:6px;'><span style='color: #73a724;font-weight: bold;'>Tel:</span> +44 203 051 1214</li>
                <li style='list-style-type: none;margin-bottom:6px;'><span style='color: #73a724;font-weight: bold;'>Fax:</span> +44 207 657 3322</li>
                <li style='list-style-type: none;margin-bottom:6px;'><span style='color: #73a724;font-weight: bold;'>E-mail:</span> info@test.co.uk </li>
                <li style='list-style-type: none;margin-bottom:6px;'><span style='color: #73a724;font-weight: bold;'>Web:</span> www.test.co.uk</li>
            </ul>
        </div>";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: test <info@test.co.uk>' . "\r\n";

    $success = mail($emails, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I think there is some mixed here.

If still not work, maybe you should install this plugin [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) with your gmail information and try your code again. Hope that help!